# How to implement a backend with AJAX, PHP, and MySQL for dynamic video sources when using Google TV Templates?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-tv

For people interested in doing web apps for Google TV, especially those with video content, the easiest way is use Google TV Templates: https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/gtv-templates.

The original Google TV Templates were developed with video source files hard coded in Javascript file.  A number of people have asked about how to implement a backend with PHP and MySQL and store video sources there so that they can be dynamically loaded from frontend within the Templates.  The following article was written to address this question.

https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/ajax_gtv_templates_tutorial

The tutorial walks you through how to set up a database in MySQL (i.e. schema, sample data),  PHP code to serve data, and modified Javascript to do AJAX loading.

Currently to add video source data into the database, one can use straight SQL but it may be more desirable to build a PHP admin front end.

A bug was recently reported by Maurizio on Google TV Developers +page: https://plus.google.com/117492290125593364976/posts:

"Hi, i downloaded the html5 template mysql version. it is working fine but if i add more than one category , the last one added is repeted. Do u have any idea of how i can fix this problem? many thanks."

I'll follow up with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

A fix to this bug is available and a new download is at: http://gtv-resources.googlecode.com/files/gtv_template2_ajax_php_mysql.tgz

The actual fix is in this php file:

http://code.google.com/p/gtv-resources/source/browse/trunk/gtv_template2_ajax_php_mysql/videosources.php

If there is interest, please ask a question and I'll write up an admin page as well.